# Event on chekbox

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

I'm developing a Java interface coding in `swing` and I use a checkbox.
I would like that when I click on the checkbox it make a continuous event (because in this event I make a weft and I send it to a microcontroller) but I don't know how to do.
I tried to make an `ActionListener` but it make the action only one time.

Who can help me please ? :)

Here is the code I tried :

```
checkbox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    // ------------------------------------------------------------|
                    // Déclaration des variables de la trame de la liaison
                    // montante|
                    // -----------------------------------------------------------|
                    float capGPS = -30;
                    float longi = 30;
                    float lat = 50;
                    float h = 50;
                    float capM = 50;
                    float V = 50;
                    float R = 50;
                    float Tsurvol = 50;
                    float Dist = 45;
                    float phiE = -30;
                    float thetaE = 30;
                    float psiE = 45;
                    float psiScan = 30;
                    float TfCam = 0;

                    String strRealFR = thetafld.getText();

                    float thetaCam = Float.valueOf(strRealFR);

                    float psiCam = Float.valueOf(psifld.getText());
                    byte[] length = new byte[1];
                    length[0] = 7;
                    byte[] typeMission = new byte[1];
                    typeMission[0] = 1;
                    // -----------------------------------------------------|
                    // Initialisation du tableau d'octets contenant la
                    // trame|
                    // ----------------------------------------------------|
                    byte[] trame = new byte[0];
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            "$".getBytes());// StarFlag
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            "!".getBytes());// Flag Nav
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            "M".getBytes());// Mémorisation
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            Tools.convertSingleToBytes(capGPS));// CapGPS
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            Tools.convertSingleToBytes(longi));// Longitude
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            Tools.convertSingleToBytes(lat));// Latitude
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            Tools.convertSingleToBytes(h));// Altitude
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            Tools.convertSingleToBytes(capM));// Cap
                                                                // Magnétque
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            Tools.convertSingleToBytes(V));// Vitesse
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            Tools.convertSingleToBytes(R));// Rayon de
                                                            // révolution
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            Tools.convertSingleToBytes(Tsurvol));// Temps de
                                                                    // survol
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            Tools.convertSingleToBytes(Dist));// Distance
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            "Rt".getBytes());// Retour au point initial
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            "§".getBytes());// flag attitude
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            Tools.convertSingleToBytes(phiE));// Angle de
                                                                // roulis
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame, typeMission);// Type
                                                                            // de
                                                                            // mission
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            Tools.convertSingleToBytes(thetaE));// Angle de
                                                                // tangage
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            Tools.convertSingleToBytes(psiE));// Angle de
                                                                // lacet
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            "#".getBytes());// mode de fonctionnement
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            "o".getBytes());// Marche/Arret
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            Tools.convertSingleToBytes(-thetaCam));// Tangage
                                                                    // caméra
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            Tools.convertSingleToBytes(psiCam));// Angle de
                                                                // lacet
                                                                // caméra
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            Tools.convertSingleToBytes(psiScan));// vitesse
                                                                    // de
                                                                    // balayage
                                                                    // caméra
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            Tools.convertSingleToBytes(TfCam));// tems de
                                                                // fonctionnement
                                                                // de la
                                                                // caméra
                    trame = Tools.concatenateByteArrays(trame,
                            "*".getBytes());// fin de trame

                    try {
                        if (port != null) {
                            fluxEcriture.write(trame);

                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                    }

                } // fin actionPerformed

            });
```

(Sorry for my bad English, I'm a french student .... :/ )

Comment: What do you want by "continuous event"? a loop within event, or a chain of events?

Comment: I would like the actions in the event "repeat" while the checkbox is selected

Comment: do you mean, that you want the actions in the event handler to repeat for the entire duration a checkbox is selected?

Comment: yes it's what I would like to make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing that much non-gui related work on the EDT anyways.

Create a new `java.util.Timer` and call `Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate` in the `actionPerformed` method. **Do not use `javax.swing.Timer`**, as it executes on the EDT, and it seems you are dealing with a lot of non-gui related things in your `actionPerformed` method. Instead, use `EventQueue.invokeLater` to post things that ARE gui related to the EDT

You need to pass the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method a `TimerTask` (which contains the code you want to execute repeatedly), the delay amount (wait time befire starting the task) and the period amount (delay time between each execution):

```
java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();

ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                //code to execute repeatedly
            }
        }, 0, 0);
};
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand where I have to include the action on the checkbox ... :(

Comment: @GaelDoManh I'm not sure what you mean. Do you know how to add a listener to the checkbox? You're doing it in the code you're showing us

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `timers` and repeat the code which you want to on checking the `checkbox`

```
 Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //do your stuff here
                }
            });
            timer.start();
```